# Retrieve last row in array using end($array)

Tags: php, mysql

After doing some research I hear that to retrieve the last row on an array I can use `end($arrayname)`

However when putting this into my page it does not retrieve the last, but the first in the array.

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Items";
$resultSet2 = mysql_query($query2);


while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$lastElement = end($row2);
echo $lastElement;
}
```

Looping through the array like this will loop through and display every row in the array one after the other:
Agate & Labradorite Necklace.jpgAgate Necklace.jpgAventurine, Citrine and Carnelian Necklace.jpg

However I was under the impression it should simply repeat the last item (Carnelian necklace.jpg) every time

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$lastElement = end($row2);
echo $lastElement
```

This will print the first item in the array. Any ideas what is causing this to happen?

Comment: Guess what `$row2` is. That's right - a *row*. You're selecting the last value of the associated array that is the row (if the last column is `name`, you'd show name). If you want the last *row* in the table and not the last *column* in the row use `SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying `end` to `$row2`, which *already* represents a row of data. This makes `$lastElement` be the last column of each row (the `while` iterates over rows).

It would not make sense to fetch N items just so that you can repeat the last one of them N times (in addition: your SQL query does not specify a sort order, so which item is going to be last is also unknown to you). If you wanted to do something like that you would fetch one item using `LIMIT 1` and the number N using an appropriate query and finally simply use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why to do so much trouble just select the last row in the query as

```
SELECT * FROM Items order by primary_key desc limit 1
```

`primary_key`  is the column name of your table which is primary key

Answer (score 0):

Try with array_pop function in php

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$lastElement = array_pop($row2);
echo $lastElement
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Items DESC limit 1";
$resultSet2 = mysql_query($query2);


while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo $lastElement = $row2;
}
```